# How do I delete images from Firebase Storage Android through a Query?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am creating a method called "Delete My Account" in my Application and to delete all the user stuff I created some Queries.

**This is the database situation:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaUYh.jpg

As you can see this user posted a Book with the own image, guessing that user posted more books, How can I delete all books images which the user posted?

**That's my code to delete:**

```
private DatabaseReference mUserBook;

private Query user_book;

mUserBook = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Books");

user_book = mUserBook.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(currentUid);

user_book.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.getValue() != null){

                for(DataSnapshot book_Snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    book_Snap.getRef().removeValue();
                }
            }
```

In this way it will delete all the data but not the book images if he posted more books in this case, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you delete the whole book. Try to use `book_Snap.getRef().child('image').removeValue();`. This way it will only delete the image child.

Edit:

To delete the book itself from the storage I would suggest you to use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). A listener for removing a book would look like this:

```
// Listens on removing a book
exports.removeBookImageFromStorage = functions.database.ref('/Books/{bookId}/image/').onDelete(event => {
    // Remove image from the Storage - you can get the imageUrl or the bookId from the event variable
});`
```

Comment: if I delete the child then it doesnt remove the image itself in Storage Reference right? how can I delete it as well ?

Comment: Thats right yeah, I would suggest that you make a CloudFunction for that. CloudFunctions can be used when someone makes changes (creating, editing or deleting) in the database. You can read about it in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). After deleting a book, you can delete it in the storage. I edited my answer so you have a hint for making such a listener.